# Working with Ethereum Light Wallet. Converting a string of text into a 12 word mnemonic?

Tags: addresses, light-clients, eth-lightwallet

I'm trying to create an ethereum address from a string of text using https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet

But it seems that the wallet requires a 12 word mnemonic in order to generate an address. I couldn't figure out a way where I can provide a string of text to generate the 12 word mnemonic which generates the address. How would I go about this?

The input has to be a string of text, in my case its a bitcoin private key that needs to converts into a 12 word mnemonic to get an ethereum address. If I can use any string of text and skip the mnemonics, that would work too!

Comment: I haven't used this wallet, but are you sure the wallet won't generate a 12-word mnemonic for you? And then you copy the mnemonic down, you can enter it later to regain access to your wallet if your hard drive dies.

Answer (score 1):

12-word mnemonics were brought in with BIP39.

You can generate them online with this tool: https://iancoleman.github.io/bip39/

As far as I know, you can't use a string of text, unless there's a separate tool someone has written to create the 12 words from the entropy in such a string.

There are "ideal" conditions that must be met to make a "good" list of 12 words, as described in the specification under [Wordlists](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki#wordlist). If you *could* generate such a list from a Bitcoin private key, there'd be no guarantee they'd be "good" words that created the required amount of entropy.